# Azure DevOps Pipelines - run YAML pipeline only when previous run was successful

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a Build pipeline (defined in yaml) in Azure DevOps Pipelines which has a cron-trigger that is executed nightly. Sometimes a pipeline run fails and needs manual re-run or cleanup. In that case I would like the trigger not to fire again if the previous execution was not yet successfully completed.

If this cannot be configured on the trigger itself, I'd be also fine to write a simple task that I run as a first step in my pipeline. But so far I didn't see a good way how to do so?

The pipeline has access to its own build definition id, but the only way I see to access previous runs would be through the ADO CLI - and this creates the problem that the executing Azure Service Principle would now need permissions on the ADO project.

Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: do you talk about trigger one pipeline after another? If so here is a link to [ms docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops)

Comment: no. the pipeline gets triggered every night on a cron-trigger - independently from each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, after some trial-and-error I built a solution based on ADO CLI. I integrate this task in my pipeline as the very first step

```
  - job: checkpipelinestatejob
    displayName: 'Check Pipeline state'
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Schedule')) # only check this for scheduled runs (by cron-trigger)
    steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      name: 'checkPreviousPipelineRun'
      displayName: 'Check previous pipeline run status'
      env:
          AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)
      inputs:
        targetType: inline
        script: |

          # Login to Azure DevOps Extension is happening automatically using ENV AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT which is set above
          # Set default Azure DevOps organization and project
          az devops configure --defaults organization=$(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri) project=$(System.TeamProject) --use-git-aliases true

          # List last pipeline runs (just for easier debugging)
          echo "*** Last five runs of this pipeline:"
          az pipelines runs list --pipeline-ids $(System.DefinitionId) --status all --top 5 --output table

          # Fetch result of the previous scheduled run (--top 1)
          $previousRunResult = $(az pipelines runs list --pipeline-ids $(System.DefinitionId) --status completed --reason schedule --top 1 --query "[].result" -o tsv)

          echo "*** Previous scheduled run of this pipeline was completed with status: $previousRunResult"

          if($previousRunResult -eq "failed")
          {
            throw "*** Previous scheduled pipeline run did not complete successfully. Not running another pipeline. Please cleanup manually and retry."
          }
```